# Open file using XLWT

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I'm using python to write to openoffice calc file.
How can I open the file after I finish writing to it?
(Open meaning the user would see it before my program would exit?)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything to accomplish what you want? Done any research?

Answer (score 0):

Use

for Windows:
`os.startfile(filename)`

for Linux

```
subprocess.Popen2(filename)
```

Comment: thanks. I tried it but I got:

'module' object has no attribute 'startfile'

Answer (score 0):

If you use [PyUno](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/PyUNO_bridge) you can load the current document

```
document = desktop.getCurrentComponent()
```

another helpful document [here](http://lucasmanual.com/mywiki/OpenOffice)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone,
I'm using ubuntu so this is what worked for me:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("path_to_file")
```